# How to forward SSH tunnel to a CIDR range or several local IPs on the local host

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssh, ssh-tunneling

I would like to open an SSH tunnel as follows:

```bash
ssh -f -N -L 172.16.0.0/12:5433:127.0.0.1:5432 server
```

but this command raises an error:

```bash
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: getaddrinfo(172.16.0.0/12): Name or service not known
Could not request local forwarding.
```

How could I forward the tunnel to several interfaces on the local machine?

I want to achieve that to make it possible to access the tunnel from any docker container in this CIDR range `172.16.0.0/12`.

Both the server and the local machine are on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS using `OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022`

As a workaround I can open one tunnel per local IPs now or do open the tunnel more broadly as:

```bash
ssh -f -N -L 0.0.0.0:5433:127.0.0.1:5432 server
```

which I don't necessarily want.

Answer (score -1):

Think SSH Tunnels wont work tin this way.
I recommend Wireguard to secure your container connections.

Have a look at https://www.linuxserver.io/blog/routing-docker-host-and-container-traffic-through-wireguard

The concept is based on a separate Wireguard container (lscr.io/linuxserver/wireguard:latest ). This is the Wireguard server

The containers to be secured get in touch with this. The traffic can then be usefully distributed on the Wireguard container with routing.
In order to keep the whole thing maintainable, a shared folder for the client configs is created (for the Wireguards clients)

Because all this is relatively complex, I recommend first writing everything down on paper to prepare the IPs and Routings.

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Please have a look at the Asking and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help), especially the advice on [writing good answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). While referencing external websites is perfectly fine, you should provide the context in your answer, as if the target disappears for any reason your answer becomes useless. This is why link-only answers like this are pretty fast [deleted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/439514)

Comment: This looks like it could be a good answer if you take the time to expand on the link a bit, quote the relevant sections and explain why you feel it's appropriate. Please do so.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).